# How can i slow down QSpinBox scrolls while holding Up/Down (Keyboard)

Tags: c++, qt

The scenario is the following:
When my active Widget is a QSpinBox, I can change the value by clicking or holding a click on an arrow of the box or by pressing or **holding** <kbd>Page Up</kbd>/<kbd>Page Down</kbd>/  <kbd>▲</kbd>  /  <kbd>▼</kbd>  .

The problem is, that i have some hardware communications on *valueChanged()* which needs some milliseconds.
While i permascroll (mouse) or hold the click on a boxes arrow, this isn't a problem, because the scroll seems to be slower here (acceleration off), but when i use my keyboard (acceleration also off), the scrollspeed is much faster which causes the timing problem. The application slows down, then freezes for some seconds until the event queue is finished.

I need to allow using the keyboard input (including holding the keyboard key), so I'd like to know if there is a way to slow down key repeat rate of arrow/page up/down.

Actually I'm triggering a 200 msec oneshot timer on value changed, which passes the spinbox value on timeout. The timer will only be triggered if it's not running. That means when i change the value it will always have a 200 msec delay and the update frequency can only be *5 updates/sec* or slower. It actually works, but I'd really like to improve this by reducing the key repeat rate somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Ok no I see problem. Here problem is keyboard replaying character on button hold.

To overcome this without direct interaction with keyboard, I would try use [event filter](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.6/qobject.html#installEventFilter). Observe [key press events](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.6/qkeyevent.html) and reject some of them when they are arriving to fast.

Comment: This doesn't really solve my problem, because the event filter also needs a timer in this case and I don't really want to use a timer.

Comment: no you don't need the timer. You need only calculate time difference since last event so you need to store time of last passed event to decide if next event is passed or ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Your device communication subsystem has two states: busy and available. When it's busy, you should schedule an update of a particular variable in your target, but don't execute it just yet. When the previous communications are done, and the subsystem is available, it should pick up any outstanding changes and propagate them.